# Concatenating strings with 

Tags: r, string-concatenation

I have a data frame with several variables. What I want is create a string using (*concatenation*) the variable names but with something else in between them...

Here is a simplified example (**number of variables reduced to only 3 whereas I have actually many**)

**Making up some data frame**

```
 df1 <- data.frame(1,2,3) # A one row data frame
  names(df1) <- c('Location1','Location2','Location3')
```

**Actual code...**

```
  len1 <- ncol(df1)
  string1 <- 'The locations that we are considering are'  
    for(i in 1:(len1-1))   string1 <- c(string1,paste(names(df1[i]),sep=','))

  string1 <- c(string1,'and',paste(names(df1[len1]),'.'))
  string1
```

This gives...

```
[1] "The locations that we are considering are"
[2] "Location1"                          
[3] "Location2"                          
[4] "Location3 ."
```

But I want

**The locations that we are considering are Location1, Location2 and Location3.**

I am sure there is a much simpler method which some of you would know...
Thank you for you time...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Are you looking for the `collapse` argument of `paste`?

```
> paste (letters [1:3], collapse = " and ")
[1] "a and b and c"
```

Comment: In that case, `paste ("Considering ", paste (head (names (df), -1), collapse = ", "), " and ", tail (names (df), 1), ".", sep = "").

Answer (score 5):

The fact that these are names of a data.frame does not really matter, so I've pulled that part out and assigned them to a variable `strs`.

```
strs <- names(df1)
len1 <- length(strs)
string1 <- paste("The locations that we are considering are ", 
                 paste(strs[-len1], collapse=", ", sep=""),
                 " and ",
                 strs[len1], 
                 ".\n", 
                 sep="")
```

This gives

```
> cat(string1)
The locations that we are considering are Location1, Location2 and Location3.
```

Note that this will not give sensible English if there is only 1 element in `strs`.

The idea is to collapse all but the last string with comma-space between them, and then paste that together with the boilerplate text and the last string.

Answer (score 2):

If your main goal is to print the results to the screen (or other output) then use the `cat` function (whose name derives from concatenate):

```
> cat(names(iris), sep=' and '); cat('\n')
Sepal.Length and Sepal.Width and Petal.Length and Petal.Width and Species
```

If you need a variable with the string, then you can use `paste` with the `collapse` argument.  The `sprintf` function can also be useful for inserting strings into other strings (or numbers into strings).

Answer (score 0):

An other options would be:

```
library(stringr)
str_c("The location that we are consiering are ", str_c(str_c(names(df1)[1:length(names(df1))-1], collapse=", "), names(df1)[length(names(df1))], sep=" and "))
```